# Java 8 Map with Static Function in External Class

Tags: java

I have a static function in a `Utils` class which maps Bean1 to Bean2,

```
public class Utils {

   public static Bean2 bean1ToBean2(Bean1 bean1) {
      Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2(...);
      return bean2;    
   }
}
```

Now I need to use it, but there's something wrong with the syntax:

```
beans2 = beans1.stream().map(this::Utils.bean1ToBean2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There's a syntax error,

```
The target type of this expression must be a functional interface.
```

Comment: Change `this::Utils.bean1ToBean2` to `Utils::bean1ToBean2`

Comment: In your context, `map` expects a `Function<Bean1, Bean2>`, and the method reference `Utils::bean1ToBean2` fulfills just that functional interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
 map(Utils::bean1ToBean2)
```

Or if you are in the same class just:

```
map(this::bean1ToBean2)
```